# How to know if the application still is up to date with the current code in editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-luna

I'm using Eclipse Luna. When I'm running an application in debug mode that is connected to the debugger and I change something in the code the application uses the new code via the **Hot Code Replace** function of eclipse. This function does stop to work if the code changes affect e.g. names of called methods. Then sometimes my application crashes missing a method with an obsolete name (that's ok!). But sometimes my applications simply does not update to the new code and I don't know if this is the case.

It cost me a lot of time to restart the application on every change (> 5min) as well as when I have to figure out if a misbehavior of my application is a consequence of a new bug or simply my new code has not been **hot replaced** by eclipse.

**Is there any hint / plugin in eclipse that shows me if the debugged application is still up to date with the current code changes?**

Comment: I have ticked "Build Automatically" which triggers Hot Replace whenever I save a code file if I have a debug session running. If the replace fails eclipse pops up an error message.

Comment: I've activated the same configuration. Though the dialog does not pop up every time. I don't know when it isn't.

Comment: I have a feeling that it won't pop up if your code has compilation errors but that it does pop up if it compiles but the Hot Replace fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the debug view, you can see the threads in it like this:

`Thread [main] (Running)`

if the code changes and it cannot refresh it it reads:

`Thread [main] (may be out of sync)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong settings and did not read well. The problem was a misconfigured Eclipse. I somehow disabled the option to popup an error:

[image]